# Linux xdotool Key Stuck

Tags: linux, bash, xdotool

I've been making a script which makes you unable to exit the terminal, unless you enter "yes". I've used this command to disable the Alt key temporarily.

```
xdotool keyup Alt_L Alt_R
```

I am now unable to "release" the key and my Alt key doesn't work properly anymore.
I did try

```
xdotool keydown Alt_L Alt_R
```

which resulted in constant pressing of the Alt key.
I did find out, that uninstalling xdotool makes the Alt key working again. 
Yet I still need the Xdotool. Therefore this is not a option for me.

Can you help me "release" the Alt key and neither make it pressed, nor permanently unpressed?

**Some additional information:**

I am using Linux Mint 18. 
And my script is running with bash.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: yeah it was about programming

Answer (score 0):

Okay you will hate me for this answer. My mistake was that I had "Save session" in the options restarting. This resulted in a forkbomb curl command loop and it didn't release the alt key. I will try this keydown command again and then see what happens. I am not sure if this is only on Linux mint 18, or on other Linux distros.